# "ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" on a specific PC

Tags: python, windows, sockets, networking

I'm getting this error only on my PC, that means the code is not a problem but here is how it looks like:

```py
host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
server = (host,5000)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(server)
while True:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    if data:
        #code
```

I'm sure that's a windows error but is there any solution to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [socket.error: \[Errno 10054\] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host (python2.7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35542404/socket-error-errno-10054-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-re)

Comment: @sqz Nope, that didn't help. Perhaps the best way is to catch the error with "Try Except" when the server (or client) terminates forcibly :(